# Updating item in place in list

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to make a multi select grid. But when I select an item, the screen flashes a bit and the grid scrolls to the top. I understand that this is to do with the grid thinking it's an entirely new list but I'm not sure how to solve it.

My UI State model:

```
internal sealed interface SelectCategoriesUiState {

    object Loading : SelectCategoriesUiState

    data class Content(
        val selectableCategories: List<SelectableCategory>
    ) : SelectCategoriesUiState {
        data class SelectableCategory(
            val isSelected: Boolean,
            val name: String,
            val slug: String
        )
    }
}
```

And my ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
internal class SelectedCategoriesViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val categoriesRepository: CategoryRepository,
    private val profileRepository: ProfileRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow<SelectCategoriesUiState>(
        SelectCategoriesUiState.Loading
    )
    val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {

            profileRepository.getProfileFlow()
                .combine(categoriesRepository.getCategories()) { profileResource, categoryResource ->
                    val resources = listOf(profileResource, categoryResource)
                    _uiState.update {
                        if (allAreSuccess(listOf(profileResource, categoryResource))) {
                            val profile = profileResource.data
                            val categories = categoryResource.data
                            SelectCategoriesUiState.Content(
                                selectableCategories = categories?.map { category ->
                                    SelectCategoriesUiState.Content.SelectableCategory(
                                        name = category.name,
                                        isSelected = profile?.categories?.any { it.slug == category.slug } == true,
                                        slug = category.slug
                                    )
                                } ?: listOf()
                            )
                        } else if (anyAreError(resources)) {
                            SelectCategoriesUiState.Loading
                        } else {
                            SelectCategoriesUiState.Loading
                        }
                    }
                }.collect()
        }
    }

    fun onCategorySelected(slug: String) {
        _uiState.update { currentState ->
            if (currentState is SelectCategoriesUiState.Content) {
                val index = currentState.selectableCategories.indexOfFirst { it.slug == slug }
                val item = currentState.selectableCategories[index]
                val isSelected = item.isSelected

                val l = currentState.selectableCategories.toMutableList()
                l[index] = item.copy(isSelected = !isSelected)
                currentState.copy(selectableCategories = l )
            } else {
                currentState
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then my grid

```
@Composable
private fun ContentState(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    uiState: SelectCategoriesUiState.Content,
    onCategorySelected: (slug: String) -> Unit
) {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
    ) {
        items(
            items = uiState.selectableCategories,
            key = { it.slug }
        ) { selectableCategory ->
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .clickable { onCategorySelected(selectableCategory.slug) }
                    .background(
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
                        color = Theme.colors.surface
                    )
                    .height(80.dp),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                ThemeSystem.Text.BodyMedium(text = selectableCategory.name)
                if (selectableCategory.isSelected) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .background(
                                shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
                                color = Theme.colors.secondary.copy(alpha = 0.2f)
                            )
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The UI itself isn't perfect as I'm trying to get the functionality in first.

Any help is much appreciated.